# JSF 2.2 Primefaces 4.0 <p:dialog> not displaying with ManagedBeans

Tags: jsf, primefaces

dialog not displaying with ManagedBeans. if datatable is not connecting Managedbean, dialog is displaying. i think dialog and datatable tags codes are correct. Maybe it depends on managedbeans pls suggest me.

```
<p:commandButton value="insert Qstn" onclick="PF('dlgAdd').show();"/>

<p:dataTable var="lstQstn" value="#{qstnBean.lstQstn}" rows="5" sortMode="multiple"
                             paginator="true"
                           paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink}  {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}  {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5, 10, 15">

                    <p:column headerText="group" sortBy="#{lstQstn.qGroup}">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lstQstn.qGroup}"/>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="qstn">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lstQstn.qQuestion}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="type" sortBy="#{lstQstn.qType}">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lstQstn.qType}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="AskedCnt">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lstQstn.qAskedCnt}"/>

                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="state">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lstQstn.qState}"/>

                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>

<p:dialog id="dlg" header="fielder" widgetVar="dlgAdd" appendTo="@(body)">
<p:panelGrid>
....
</p:panelGrid>
<p:commandButton value="Хадгал" oncomplete="PF('dlgAdd').hide();"/>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Did you use the `dialog` tag inside `<h:form>` tag ?

Comment: Yes, datatable and dialogs are inside <h:form> tag

Comment: Bring the dialog outside of the general `<h:form/>` and put a separate `<h:form/>` inside the dialog @Amuna

Comment: dialog is displaying when datatable is empty, But when i put datas to datatable, dialog not showing. i do not understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an end tag for one of your columns:

```
 <p:column headerText="qstn">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lstQstn.qQuestion}"/>
```

Comment: i know that i removed some tags and some explains so close tag removed

Comment: Do you have a message tag in your program that could display any potential errors? Did you check for any JS errors on the page?